# How to transfare data from DB to some buiseness entity

Tags: android, database, architecture

Now I am working on Android application which has one main Activity that is displaying some data via GLSurface. This data can be changed in many ways. For this I have several fragments with some lists of variants with extra logic. Problem is that I need somehow transfer data from one place to another.

*For example:*

I have fragment with list of elements. I used RecyclerView with custom adapter. I am filling list with data from DB. `SomeThingDBEntity` for example. When I am getting it from Room DB (using Room entities), but it has some extra fields that only required for showing elements in RecyclerView. I need to send user's choice from adapter to fragment, then from fragment to activity, than activity sends it to some class that incapsulates logic of work with GLSurface. `SomeThingGLentity` for example. Now I am passing only fields, that requered by `SomeThingGLentity` for showing data (`int`, `String` etc.), but in future this list can grow. I can also send directly `SomeThingDBEntity` and get required fields only in the end when apply changes to `SomeThingGLentity`. But is it OK to use Room DB entity this way?

Is there any better way of doing this? I can also create third class which will only contain required fields. But where to place and how to call it? Maybe there are some patterns or guidelines of best way of doing it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need a data mapper. Something similar to this - https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture/blob/master/data/src/main/java/com/fernandocejas/android10/sample/data/entity/mapper/UserEntityDataMapper.java.
If you use this approach, you will be able to encapsulate the transformation logic from your DBEntity to your BusinessEntity, and if you will change the data format in one of them, only your mapper will need to be edited.